# Are "We've all" and "we all have" the same?

Tags: meaning-in-context, contractions

i had been reading a paper but i haven't understood a paragraph. Can you help me?

paragraph as follows

"**We've all left meetings feelings good** about what we discussed only to later wonder why so little happened as a result? Where did the momentum go?

does it mean same that 2 sentences "we've all left" and "we all have left"?

Answer (score 2):

To me, putting *all* before the auxiliary feels awkward, and I would only do it to put extra emphasis on *all*.

So, I would normally say:

> *We have all left* rather than *We all have left*
>
> *We are all going* rather than *We all are going*
>
> *We will all come* rather thant *We all will come*.

Using the *We all* form for those sounds to me as if somebody has said that only some of use were leaving, going, coming, and the speaker is contradicting this with *we all*.

That is the case with an auxiliary, whether it is contracted or not. So

> *We've all left* = *We have all left*

When there is no auxiliary, just the main verb, of course *all* has to precede it, so

> *We all have hats*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case they are interchangeable and mean the same thing. I think the confusion from that bolded phrase comes from the 's' at the end of feelings.  To be correct, it should read like this:

**We've all left meetings feeling good**

But yes, "We've all left meetings" and "We all have left meetings" or even "We have all left meetings" would all mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Both are the same meaning, however, “we have all left” indicates to this moment (by now) whereas “we all have left” doesn’t refer to this moment. This is my understanding of the difference.

Comment: I dont agree about the difference. There is no difference in the time indicated. The only difference I can see - and it's very slight - is that the first one is probably universal: it's about something that everybody has done, whereas the second suggests a limited "all": it's about _us_ - our particular group of people.

Answer (score 0):

**We've all have left meetings feeling good**: All of us at some point in time have done this. We've all experienced this in our lives and we know it well, because it has happened to us before.

**We all left (the?) meetings feeling good**: All of us attended several meetings in the speaker's present time, and we all left them feeling really good.

Both phrases are correct if used in the correct context.

Answer (score 0):

¨We've all¨ means ¨we have all¨

For instance: ¨We've all been to a restaurant.¨ This shows that we all went to a restaurant.

¨We all have¨ is in a possessive tense. This means it shows ownership.

For instance: ¨We all have hats.¨ This means that we all own hats.

The two terms are sometimes interchangeable, but have slightly different meanings.